# how to convert a list into html column in python

Tags: python, html, list

I have been trying to work with python and using jinja template for my HTML rendering.
The problem I have is that , I have two seperate lists.

Column_List  `[col_name1,col_name2,....]`

Data_List

```
[val1_col_name1,val2_col_name2,...]
[val3_col_name1,val4_col_name2,...]
[val1_col_name1,val2_col_name2,...]
```

So , any pointers on how do I convert this to an HTML table with column name and with an assosiated row data ?

col1  col2  col3 ...

dat1  dat2  dat3

dat4  dat5  dat6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that your variables are passed to jinja with the using the same names:

```
col_names = [col_name1, col_name2, ...]

data = [
    [val1_col_name1, val2_col_name2, ...]
    [val3_col_name1, val4_col_name2, ...]
    [val1_col_name1, val2_col_name2, ...]
]
```

Then, the following jinja snippet is not that complicated:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        {% for col_name in col_names %}
        <th>{{ col_name }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for row in data %}
        <tr>
            {% for cell in row %}
                <td>{{ cell }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Garet!. I used a similar approach and it did work. The only thing i was worried about was the ordering, and I had my original data in a dict with sorts them in a random order.

Comment: Use a list or an OrderedDict then ;)